# How to pass data from a component to far component in vue js 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

I can't find a way to pass data from a component to a non child component in vue.
I'm working with a blade file and I have a component to toggle between darkmode and lightmode. I want my dark logo to show if dark and light logo to show if light. The problem is provide/inject can't solve the issue I see in Vue dev tool that my value is provided but when i check the other component the injected value is undefined. I did it before in a dropdown component and i was able to pass the value because It was about one parent component and its child but now I can't do it.

I need a way to pass data from my Switchdark.vue component to Svglogodark.vue component.

My Switchdark.vue

```js
<template>
    <div
        class="flex cursor-pointer items-center justify-between"
        @click="modeToggle"
    >
        <div
            class="flex h-4 w-12 items-center rounded-full bg-gray-300 p-1 duration-300 ease-in-out"
            :class="{ 'bg-green-400': toggleActive }"
        >
            <div
                class="h-3 w-3 transform rounded-full bg-white shadow-md duration-300 ease-in-out"
                :class="{ 'translate-x-7': toggleActive }"
            ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { provide, ref } from "vue";
import Svglogodark from "./Svglogodark.vue";
export default {
    components: [Svglogodark],
    props: ["theme"],
    data() {
        return {
            toggleActive: false,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.theme === "false") {
            this.light();
        } else {
            this.dark();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dark() {
            document.querySelector("body").classList.add("dark");
            this.toggleActive = true;
            this.$emit("dark");
        },
        light() {
            document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("dark");
            this.toggleActive = false;
            this.$emit("light");
        },

        modeToggle() {
            if (
                this.darkMode ||
                document.querySelector("body").classList.contains("dark")
            ) {
                this.light();
            } else {
                this.dark();
            }
            const isDarkModeOn = this.toggleActive;
            createCookie("isDarkModeOn", isDarkModeOn.toString(), 60 * 60 * 24);
        },
    },
    setup() {
        const toggleActive = ref(toggleActive);

        provide("toggleActive", toggleActive);

        return {
            toggleActive,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

My Svglogodark.vue:

```js
<template>
    <svg
        v-if="toggleActive"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="170"
        height="70"
        viewBox="0 0 4792 1625"
    >
  
    </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    inject: ["toggleActive"],
    created() {
        console.log(this.toggleActive);
    },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

I will have two SVG and i want them to show if I'm in dark mode or not.

Comment: You can use a "store" (search for Vue 3 store on the internet, you'll find tutorials). A store can be accessed across components and is reactive data, just like in your components.

Comment: Will give it a shot and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm finding a very hard time doing so because store.js doesn't recognize $emit and i have to copy my code to it in order for the toggleActive change in store.js

Comment: You will have to change how your code works, yes. You don't use `$emit` in this case (maybe additionally). You instead change the variable in the store. Other components who use that variable will automatically update themselves, because of reactivity of the store.

Comment: Shit it works! I changed my code completely. Thank you so much that store thing worked as I want exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vuex here you can learn about it. [vuex-docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

Or

You can use simple way that is `LocalStorage`

```js
\\store item
localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');

\\you can get anywhere
var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

console.log(theme); //'dark'
```

Comment: Will this work in production? I mean if i store something locally, after publishing my site will any user have the same local storage?

Comment: Also in regards of Vueex If i called my 'toggleActive' from $store and done the function from my component the value of toggleActive always be the value i hard code in store not the value that comes from the other component. I'm completely lost here.

Comment: @MostafaSaid Store is in the client side and each user will have its own store.

Comment: So this means if i used this method, in production this won't do me anything right?

Comment: So, you want to store in server side?

Comment: @MostafaSaid In your example you want to implement a bright/dark theme. That is certainly per user. Saving that setting in the browser is enough.

Comment: I solved it I cut all methods to store and it works